# How can I play a custom sound in WatchOS 3 that will playback on the watch speakers

Tags: audio, sprite-kit, watchos-3

I've read that we can now play custom sounds on the apple watch in watchos 3.

According to the announcement from Apple so apparently there is but I don't have an example to test it out: 3D spatial audio implemented using SCNAudioSource or SCNAudioPlayer. Instead, use playAudioSource:waitForCompletion: or the WatchKit sound or haptic APIs. Found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInwatchOS/Articles/watchOS3.html

Can someone place a simple example of this. I'm not using SceneKit in my app as I don't need it but if that's the only way to play a custom sound then I'd like to know the minimum code required to accomplish this.  Preferably in Objective c but I'll take it in whatever shape.  I'm ok using SpriteKit if that's easier also.

Here's what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
SCNNode * audioNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];

SCNAudioSource * audioSource = [SCNAudioSource audioSourceNamed:@"mysound.mp3"];
SCNAudioPlayer * audioPlayer = [SCNAudioPlayer audioPlayerWithSource:audioSource];  
[audioNode addAudioPlayer:audioPlayer];

SCNAction * play = [SCNAction playAudioSource:audioSource waitForCompletion:YES];
[audioNode runAction:play];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***This is Objective-c but can be translated into Swift***

I ended up using `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioPlayerNode` to play audio on the Apple watch.

The gist of how to do this is as follows:

I call the following inside the `init` method of my AudioPlayer (it's an NSObject subclass to encapsulate the functionality)

```
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
_audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
[_audioEngine attachNode:_audioPlayer];

AVAudioFormat *stereoFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:44100 channels:2];
[_audioEngine connect:_audioPlayer to:_audioEngine.mainMixerNode format:stereoFormat];

if (!_audioEngine.isRunning) {
    NSError* error;
    [_audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error];
}
```

I have a cache setup so I don't recreate the `AVAudioFile` assets every time I want to play a sound but you don't need to.

So next create an `AVAudioFile` object:

```
NSError *error;
NSBundle* appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[appBundle pathForResource:key ofType:@"aifc"]];
AVAudioFile *asset = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:url &error];
```

Then play that file:

```
[_audioPlayer scheduleFile:asset atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
[_audioPlayer play];
```

UPDATE: If the app goes to sleep or is put to the background there is a chance the audio will stop playing/fade out. By activating an Audio Session this will be prevented.

```
    NSError *error;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"AVAudioSession setCategory ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
    if (error) {
      NSLog(@"AVAudioSession setActive ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
```

I didn't go over handling any errors but this should work. Don't forget to `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` at the top of your implementation file.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this works on Watch OS 3? I'm trying to do this and I get: 'AVAudioPlayer' is unavailable: not available on watchOS

Comment: Yes I'm using it on watch os 3. You're not using an 'AVAudioPlayer' but instead 'AVAudioPlayerNode' and 'AVAudioEngine'

Comment: I'm using watchos3 as well and I'm not getting any errors but no sounds are playing from the watch or phone. I basically copied all three of your code blocks and put them together and I'm not getting anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Also @ApperleyA were you trying on the simulator or a real device?

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 I was using a real device as there's a bug in watchos 3's SDK that prevents the app from building when you target the simulator. One thing that I didn't add to my answer was the need for activating an AudioSession (I found this out when the audio would stop playing if the app went to the background). See my updated answer for this code but if the app is in the forground it will just work.

Comment: When you say the app is in the foreground, you mean the watch app and not the main iPhone app correct? I still can't get the sound to come out of the apple watch speaker. So far you are the only person I found that says they got it working.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 Yeah I mean the watch app. The sound is playing independent of the phone through the watch, without requiring the bluetooth headset. If you want to post the code you have so far in a pastebin or email it to me @ andrew@tinyhearts.com I can check it out.

Comment: @ApperleyA, did you try to add `audio` to `UIBackgroundModes` to Watch app (not extension) info.plist?

Comment: @kelin I did do that and it worked but only after handling the audio session as well. You can see it working in an app called Quickfit. The hardest part about adding this feature was the lack of documentation.

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm, that @ApperleyA solution really works!

Here is the swift version:

```
var _audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayerNode!
var _audioEngine : AVAudioEngine!

func playAudio()
{
    if (_audioPlayer==nil) {
        _audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        _audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        _audioEngine.attach(_audioPlayer)

        let stereoFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 44100, channels: 2)
        _audioEngine.connect(_audioPlayer, to: _audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: stereoFormat)

        do {

            if !_audioEngine.isRunning {
                try _audioEngine.start()
            }

        } catch {}

    }


    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "mp3") {

        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let asset = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileUrl)

            _audioPlayer.scheduleFile(asset, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)
            _audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print ("asset error")
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the simulator

```
  let soundPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cheerMP3", ofType: "mp3")
  let soundPathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath!)
  let audioFile = WKAudioFileAsset(url: soundPathURL)
  let audioItem = WKAudioFilePlayerItem(asset: audioFile)

  let audioPlayer = WKAudioFilePlayer.init(playerItem: audioItem)

  if audioPlayer.status == .readyToPlay
  {
    audioPlayer.play()
  }
  else
  {
    print("Not ready!!")
  }
```

but only if I had a breakpoint at both audioPlayer.play() and after the last }.

dunqan, what did you put at the top of the file, the import statements? I wasn't able to include

import AVFoundation

without an error using Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: @DBourne, were you able to listen sounds from simulator?

Comment: This will work but only on the simulator or through a bluetooth headset connected to the watch. When you import AVFoundation you cannot test in the simulator anymore due to a bug in the Watch SDK, however sound will play when tested on a real device using the method described in my answer above.

Comment: I still get an error trying to add import AVFoundation (Could not build Objective-C module 'AV Foundation'). I'm using Xcode 8.2.1. Thanks